# Scala - Trait returns different objects

Tags: scala, object, traits, subtype, supertype

I have a question about traits in Scala.

I have a trait returns a type of object (AA or BB) depending on the value of parameter country.

My implementattion covers the following approach:

```
trait firstT{

  def GetType(country: String) : OType =  {
      //i would like to call OType.load(country)
  }
}


  trait OType[T <: OType[T]] {
        def load(country: String): OType[T] = ??? 
        //I would like to return AA or BB depending on country
    }

class AA extends OType[AA] {
  override def load(country: String): AA = new AA
}



class BB extends OType[BB] {
  override def load(country: String): BB = new BB
}
```

Could you please help me on this?
Thank you
Best Regards

Comment: A compile-time type can not depend on a run time value. If you want to return either `A` or ``B` then you can use the built-in [**Either** type](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Either.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`load` is a "static" method of the trait so it belongs in the companion object not the class definition.

So the code you want might look like this

```
trait firstT {
  def GetType(country: String): OType = {
    OType.load(country)
  }
}

trait OType

object OType {
  def load(country: String): OType =
    if (country == "AA") {
      AA.load()
    } else {
      BB.load()
    }
}

class AA extends OType

object AA {
  def load(): AA = new AA
}

class BB extends OType

object BB {
  def load(): BB = new BB
}
```

If you really need the `OType` trait to be parameterised by type then use an [abstract type member](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/abstract-type-members.html):

```
trait OType {
  type T <: OType
}

class AA extends OType {
  type T = AA
}

class BB extends OType {
  type T = BB
}
```